# Flutter Firebase Authentication and/or Login is not Successful

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Firebase
Authentication: email/Password was already set to Enabled.
Realtime Database: users records exist.
Email and Password: thoroughly checked and verified correct.

below are the code for this issue;

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  void loginAndAuthenticateUser(BuildContext context) async
  {
    final User? firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailTextEditingController.text,
        password: passwordTextEditingController.text
    ).catchError((errMsg){
      displayToastMessage("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
    })).user;

    if(firebaseUser !=null)
    {
      userRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).once().then((value) => (DataSnapshot snap){
        if(snap.value != null){
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
          displayToastMessage("Login successful", context);
        }else{
          _firebaseAuth.signOut();
          displayToastMessage("No records exist. Please create new account", context);
        }
      });
    }else{
      displayToastMessage("Error: Cannot be signed in", context);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share any error messages or logs?

Comment: this is the logs when this loginAndAuthenticateUser method was executed;


W/System  ( 4611): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  ( 4611): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth( 4611): Notifying id token listeners about user ( ksYHlmLvGSMK4VjlRDnNrzyIXj83 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 4611): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( ksYHlmLvGSMK4VjlRDnNrzyIXj83 ).


There is no error messages. but I am expecting that the screen will go to MainScreen (from LoginScreen) if the login and authentication is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `await` with `catch/try`, instead of mixing with the `.then/.catchError` syntax (I don't know what's exactly in `userRef`, depending on it the database query might need to be adjusted):

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailTextEditingController.text,
      password: passwordTextEditingController.text);
  final User? firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
  if (firebaseUser != null) {
    final DatabaseEvent event = await 
      userRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).once();
    if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, 
        (route) => false);
      displayToastMessage("Login successful", context);
    } else {
      displayToastMessage("No records exist. Please create new account", 
        context);
      await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    }
  } else {
    displayToastMessage("Error: Cannot be signed in", context);
  }
} catch(e) {
  // handle error
}
```

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.